# Why isn't Euler's formula multivalued?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, multivalued-functions

[image]

So it seems that all complex exponential functions are multivalued except for ones with base $e$. Why? Shouldn't all exponentials be multivalued?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question: the text you cite is not principally about complex exponential functions like $a^z$ but rather complex power functions like $z^\alpha$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Still, fix $z$ and evaluate $w^z$ at $w = e$.

Answer (score 3):

> So it seems that all complex exponential functions are multivalued except for ones with base $e$. Why? Shouldn't all exponentials be multivalued?

Except when the exponent is an integer. Yes, but there is a **very** strong convention, that $e^z$ always means

$$\exp(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

and no other value of $w\mapsto w^z$ evaluated at $w = e$. That convention should however be explicitly introduced lest it lead to confusion if it is tacitly used.

Comment: Why? Confusion is good. Chaos is even better!